# aws cloudwatch logs insight - query and count multiple logs with different regular expressions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I need to query and count the failure logs of my app from different locations to test the performance of the APIs.

```
fields @message | filter (@message like /Failure/ and @message like /AWE/)
 | stats count()as failure by bin(1d) as AWE
```

Right now I filtered the logs with the expressions of 'Failure' and 'AWE'(one of the location) and got the below results.

```
#   AWE                              failure
1   2020-12-30T08:00:00.000+08:00    6
```

I want to continue to filter failure logs with other locations on the same widget but I can't.
So I want to know if I am missing something or it is just not possible to do the thing I want to do.

Comment: what do you means location? another loggroup? or something else?

Comment: The location is inside the log message, is part of the failure message. I am getting api calls from device in different physical location. For example, I got device in China,USA,UK and AUS, I want to know the failure calls count of each device, so I will filter key words 'failure' and 'USA'. Now I want to continue to get failure count from China,UK and AUS on the same widget.